# Can JourneyBuilder workflows be created through the API?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can I define a JourneyBuilder workflow through the Fuel API, or some other programmatic means?

Thanks

Comment: Since JourneyBuilder is still in the works I believe there wouldn't be any API interaction with it just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we have not made any Journey Builder related APIs public for production use. To create Interactions (workflows from your question) currently, you must use the Journey Builder application's GUI.

The Interactions API is currently being developed. A formal announcement will be made on Code@ (https://code.exacttarget.com).

Answer (score 1):

Updating this thread: You can now create Interactions (what you've referred to as JourneyBuilder flows) via API. This is documented here: https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/getting-started.html

Happy Coding!